# A measurable function that is not continuous at all point in the domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Is there a extended real valued (or great if real valued) measurable function that is not continuous at all the point of the domain?**what if the domain of the function is an interval?**

If there exist such a function what is it and also what is the graph of such a function?

Comment: Any function that you can probably think of that is discontinuous is also measurable. For a simple example, consider a basic step function.

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: There are **very** few nonmeasurable functions. Any function that you can write down is probably measurable.

Comment: Okay for simple function there is such function trivial though

Comment: Well what if the domain of function is an interval?

Comment: @Isao what is $\mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: \mathbf{1}_\mathbb{Q} is the characteristic function of the rationals.  It takes the values $1$ at rationals and $0$ at irrationals.